# Using selector switch to engage only one set of valves

Tags: control, automation

Can you have a selector switch engage one set of directional valves on a machine that can have 2 automated cart dampers which share a motor?

Basically the first position on the switch means no set of valves are on, the second position for cart dumper 1 and the third position for cart dumper 2?

Here is a picture of the system:

[image]

The 3 4 contact block is a KA2 N.O contact and the 1 2 contact block is a KA3  N.C contact.

The joystick on the left is what energizes either the up solenoid or down solenoid of either machine 1 or machine 2. The selector is placed there to prevent all solenoids from being on at one time.

Comment: What are directional valves? What are cart dampers? What does it mean that two cart dampers share a rotor?

Comment: A directional valve is what allows a cart dumper to move up to send material into a can think of a garbage truck when it picks up the can and dumps the trash the up valve engages when the forks are lifting the can up to dump its contents. Then when it brings the can down the down directional valve engages to lower the can. In this case you have one motor with 2 pumps therefore u have 2 cart dampers because each pump has one set of valves for machine 1 and machine 2 In this case the cart dumper

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your schematic, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

- Turn SS1 to the left you get "UP", to the right you get "DOWN".
- Turn SS2 to the left you get "TIPPER 1", to the right you get "TIPPER 2".

Depending on your selector switch choice your 1-2 contacts might also need to be NO. I know the Siemens ones had two plungers that pushed both sides.

My one suggestion would be a fifth interlocking contact on SS2 in line with the motor so that the motor can't run if a "TIPPER" isn't selected. If SS1 is in "UP" or "DOWN" position while SS2 is in neutral you'll dead head the pump. It may/may not like that -- pump dependent. Assuming that MS3 has something to do with the motor/pump.

---

Side note: seeing as this is your fourth question on EE.SE, I'd encourage you to "accept" the answers to your questions, if they've answered your question. You press the checkmark under the up/down buttons on the left of the question. Ask away though! I enjoy seeing some more automation/controls questions on EE.SE.